Jenkins dynamically provided credentials visible on UI and console
In my Jenkins script I use Mask Password plugin that does work with rather short values, like "password" or/and "pass", etc:
...
def runRegressionTests(token) {
  stage("regression tests") {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "my-encrypt-key", variable: 'encryptKey')]) {
      maskPasswords(varPasswordPairs: [[password: "${token}"]]) {
        sh "./gradlew regressionTestsNoFeedback " +
        "-PencryptKey=${encryptKey} " +
        "-Ptoken=${token} " +
        "--continue"
      }
    }
  }
}
...

and
...
def runRegressionTests(token) {
  stage("regression tests") {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "my-encrypt-key", variable: 'encryptKey')]) {
      wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: "${token}"]]]) {
        sh "./gradlew regressionTestsNoFeedback " +
        "-PencryptKey=${encryptKey} " +
        "-Ptoken=${token} " +
        "--continue"
      }
    }
  }
}
...

However when I provide JWT value it is revealed in console and UI output
How do I mask:

console output
UI output


It appears that varMaskRegexes can be used to mask desired value with approprate regex, in my case it is
...
maskPasswords(varMaskRegexes: [[key: "${token}", value: "eyJ[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*"]]) {
...
}


Update
Full example:
def runRegressionTests(token) {
  stage("regression tests") {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "my-encrypt-key", variable: 'encryptKey')]) {
      maskPasswords(varMaskRegexes: [[key: "${token}", value: "eyJ[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*"]]) {
        sh "./gradlew regressionTestsNoFeedback " +
        "-PencryptKey=${encryptKey} " +
        "-Ptoken=${token} " +
        "--continue"
      }
    }
  }
}


Turns out, regex is applied to any output that it is valid. In my logs, I expected to see only provided value masked, however other values were masked as well. Controversial benefit: on the one hand it does more than anticipated (less work, more secure), on the other hand it might be not your initial goal
